# правильный синтаксис конкатенации?

Tags: php, xml

vs code и  netbeans дружно бычат что неожидали такого от меня

```html
$xml =  <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<userInfo version="1.6">
<firstName>' .$data["firstName"]. '</firstName>
<lastName>' . $data["lastName"] . '</lastName>
<salary>' . $data["salary"] . '</salary>
<age>' . $age . '</age>
<creditScore>' .  $creditScore . '</creditScore>
</userInfo>
XML;
```

так что им нужно то???.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> так что им нужно то?

Не им нужно, а вам - перечитать про синтаксис heredoc, и в целом про экранирование переменных в строках.

```
$xml =<<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<userInfo version="1.6">
    <firstName>{$data["firstName"]}</firstName>
    <lastName>{$data["lastName"]}</lastName>
    <salary>{$data["salary"]}</salary>
    <age>$age</age>
    <creditScore>$creditScore</creditScore>
</userInfo>
XML;
```